# ggplot graph stored erase each others

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is some code which reproduces my issue:

```
x <- as.factor(1:20)
y <- 1:20
id <- as.factor(c(rep(0,19),1))
g1 <- ggplot() + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(x = x, y = y, color = id, fill = id), width = 0.5) + ggtitle("g1")
g1 # First print

y <- 20:1
g2 <- ggplot() + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(x = x, y = y, color = id, fill = id), width = 0.5) + ggtitle("g2")
g2
g1 # Second print
```

As you can see when running the code above, the first time you print g1, you have a barplot starting at (factor 1, y = 1), ending at (factor 20, y = 20).
After having created g2, if you print again g1, it looks the same than g2, except the title which isn't modified.

I'm really puzzled, any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: Changing `y` changes `g1`. Everytime you type `g1` the plot is created from scratch with the current version of `y`. The title stays unchanged because it is fixed as `"g1"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot` works best when you pull data from a data.frame rather than the global environment. If you did

```
x <- as.factor(1:20)
y <- 1:20
id <- as.factor(c(rep(0,19),1))
g1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x, y, id)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(x = x, y = y, color = id, fill = id), width = 0.5) + 
  ggtitle("g1")  
y <- 20:1
g2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x, y, id)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(x = x, y = y, color = id, fill = id), width = 0.5) + 
   ggtitle("g2")
```

everything would work fine.

The "problem" is that `ggplot` doesn't actually "build" the plot until you print it. And when you are linking to variable names with `aes()`, it just tracks the variable name, not the value. So it uses whatever the current value is when the plot prints. When we "trap" data inside a data.frame, we are capturing the current value of the variable so that we can use that later.